# Can not save in db custom json value on block

Tags: magento2, xml, json, table

In my plugin I created a new table 'myapp_staging' made of three columns: 'id', 'id_api_call' and 'f24_options_value'. In the last field I would like to save a response to my Api call in json format.

I created a new field, the path of this is Vendor\MyApp\Block\System\Config\FieldModelli.php

here below the code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\MyApp\Block\System\Config;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

class F24Modelli extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    protected $objectManager;
    
    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Fattura24\AppFatturazione\Helper\Data $helper,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function render(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $element->unsScope()->unsCanUseWebsiteValue()->unsCanUseDefaultValue();
        return parent::render($element);
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element)
    {
       return $this->F24Modelli();
    }

   
    public function F24Modelli()
    {
        $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        $apiKey = $this->helper->getConfig('myApp/generali/api_key', $storeId);
        $templates_res = $this->helper->apiCall('https://www.app.myapp.com/api/v0.3/GetTemplate', $apiKey);
        //$templates_xml = simplexml_load_string($templates_res);
        $templates_xml = simplexml_load_string($templates_res, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
        $json_templates = json_encode($templates_xml);
     
        $resource = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $tableName = $resource->getTableName('myapp_staging');
        $select = "select * from $tableName where id_api_call='1'";
        $tem_result = $connection->fetchAll($select);
        if (count($tem_result) == 0) {
            $insert = "insert into $tableName set id_api_call='1',f24_options_value='$json_templates'";
            $connection->query($insert);
        } else {
            $update = "update $tableName set id_api_call='1',f24_options_value='$json_templates'";
            $connection->query($update);
        }
        return htmlspecialchars($json_templates);
    }
}
```

first I tried to read xml in this way:

```
$templates_xml = simplexml_load_string($templates_res);
```

then I encode the response in json and succeed in saving data in my table.

In my original xml object I have got some tags inside `<[!CData[]]>` nodes
and I need the content of these nodes, so I tried this:

```
 $templates_xml = simplexml_load_string($templates_res, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

And then I encode the result in json format. Now after that I'm not more able to save my 'complete' json result in the table.

Anyone could help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found my json string was not valid, I succeeded in db saving after doing some lint programmatically (by `str_replace` method and similar)